# Javascript/JQuery not working until after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, squarespace

This code is listed on the header of all of my webpages. When I click a link on my website, I'm unable to use the buttons on the page until after I refresh. How can I fix this?

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.faqElement').click(function() {
            var faqElement = $(this);
            var question = faqElement.find('.faqQuestion');
            var answer = faqElement.find('.faqAnswer');
            if (!answer.hasClass('activeFaqAnswer')) {
              $('.faqElement').removeClass('flipButton');
              faqElement.addClass('flipButton');
              $('.activeFaqAnswer').css('max-height', '');
              $('.faqAnswer').removeClass('activeFaqAnswer');
              answer.css('max-height', 'none');
              answer.css('max-height', answer.height());
              answer.addClass('activeFaqAnswer');
            }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you share some more code? What buttons are you referring to? What classes are present on the buttons?    Are there any javascript errors logged in the console?

Comment: What happens if you were to put this at the end of your code (not just the end of header)?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a conflict with your custom script and [Squarespace's AJAX loading](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading):

> Occasionally, Ajax may conflict with embedded custom code or anchor
>   links. Ajax can also interfere with site analytics, logging hits on
>   the first page only.

So, depending on your template, you may find that disabling AJAX is a simple solution:

> You can disable Ajax in the Style Editor, with some exceptions:
>
> - Ajax can't be disabled in Skye, Foundry, or Tudor.
> - Ajax can't be disabled on the blog landing page for Farro and Haute. If you uncheck Enable Ajax Loading in these templates, they
>     will still use Ajax to load the Blog Page.
>
> To enable or disable Ajax:
>
> - In the Home Menu, click Design, and then click Style Editor.
> - Scroll down to Site: Loading.
> - Check or uncheck Enable Ajax Loading.

If you do not want to disable AJAX altogether, then [see "Option 2" in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492245/54493314#54493314) for ways to write your code so that it will work on initial page load and on AJAX page loads.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Ajax loads content dynamically and ruins your bindings.

You could call your function after each Ajax request using `$.ajaxComplete()`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function faqElementClick() {
    $('.faqElement').click(function() {
      var faqElement = $(this);
      var question = faqElement.find('.faqQuestion');
      var answer = faqElement.find('.faqAnswer');
      if (!answer.hasClass('activeFaqAnswer')) {
        $('.faqElement').removeClass('flipButton');
        faqElement.addClass('flipButton');
        $('.activeFaqAnswer').css('max-height', '');
        $('.faqAnswer').removeClass('activeFaqAnswer');
        answer.css('max-height', 'none');
        answer.css('max-height', answer.height());
        answer.addClass('activeFaqAnswer');
      }
    });
  };
  $(document).ready(faqElementClick);
  $(document).ajaxComplete(faqElementClick);
</script>
```