# JavaScript not loading because of url changes and the page doesn't load

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I'm working on a website where the page doesn't load the url just changes and the pages shows up. I added a JavaScript code to the page but the code only runs when I refresh the page and not when I click the link to get to the page. Can someone help me out?

This is the code:

```js
<script>
var idcomments_acct = '83e4fbf73e5268d6ddbbabd9e697add5';
var idcomments_post_id;
var idcomments_post_url;
</script>
<span id="IDCommentsPostTitle" style="display:none"></span>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.intensedebate.com/js/genericCommentWrapperV2.js'>
</script>
```

Comment: could you provide more code about your question?? the code you posted didn't show any problem about you description...

Answer (score 1):

In Squarespace, when your custom Javascript only works after a page refresh, it most likely has to do with [Squarespace's AJAX loading](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading):

> Occasionally, Ajax may conflict with embedded custom code or anchor
>   links. Ajax can also interfere with site analytics, logging hits on
>   the first page only.

You may be able to [**disable AJAX for your template**](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading#toc-enable-or-disable-ajax). Or, see the other approaches outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42604055/5338581