# Script only working in browser when page is refreshed SQUARESPACE

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, squarespace

I've add a script to a Squarespace site so the "read more" text is changed to "view this space" which works perfectly on the backend but doesn't seem to work in the browser unless i refresh the page.

Could anyone help me with this. I really only deal with CSS and HTML so this is a little out of my league.

I've inserted in into a code block on the pages i want to see it on.

```
 <script>
 Y.on("domready", function () {
 Y.all(".summary-read-more-link").each(function (link) {
 link.setContent("VIEW THIS SPACE");
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: check the browser **developer** tools console for errors

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks it says network is slow. How do i fix this?

Comment: Seriously? You want network advice in a coding forum

Comment: Oh god the absolute cheek of me. You don't have to engage. It's an open forum. I'm just looking for some guidance here. If you can't help me then that fine. You don't need to be so rude!!

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603151/javascript-jquery-not-working-until-after-page-reload/42604055#42604055

Comment: Ahh thanks so much @Brandon it worked!!!!

Comment: Great. Do consider up-voting the linked-to answer. Until it is, I can't mark questions such as this one as duplicate (I think I've seen this same question 6 times now, but without a single upvote or accepted answer, there's little can be done to mark duplicates).

Comment: @Brandon super! done!